# How to hot code replace in RAD/Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, ibm-rad

Writing J2EE webapps in RAD 9.0.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.0.  Our hot code replace isn't working.  We modify even the simplest of java routines (no interface changes to the class, just method internals), and yet we have to fully restart the application every time.

Googling about it seems like IBM has some instructions about setting reloadEnabled in deployment.xml, but I did that to no effect.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rapp_classload.html

I am in debug mode, I am set to have RAD detect changes and publish.  Every time I publish, the app restarts, which is an incredible time sink.  Especially since our app has alot of multi-step depth to it.

Is there some other setup I need to do to get hot method replacement to work in RAd with WAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just modifying method body in a java class and have debug mode enabled on the server already, you shouldn't need to republish for those changes to take place.  You can try turning off auto publish settings on the server (since auto publish will forces the app to be restarted).  The method body changes should get picked up automatically (assuming the method signature has not been modified).

Comment: Oh, you seem to be right.  I always thought I had to publish and did so by rote.  thanks.

Comment: That's indeed the solution while working with java classes. However, my WAS 8.5 is not replacing .html nor .xhtml when I just publish them (with manual publish), and i have to restart the server each time :(